# Implementing and using an array of generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a simple generic mapped type :

```
interface Mapped {
    str: string,
    num: number
}

type Foo<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    value: K,
    fun: (val: T[K]) => number;
}
```

Here are two examples of definitions:

```
const fooStr: Foo<Mapped, 'str'> = {
    value: 'str',
    fun: (val) => val.length
}

const fooNum: Foo<Mapped, 'num'> = {
    value: 'num',
    fun: (val) => val
}
```

If I try to define an array based on this type, and use that array :

```
type Foos = Array<Foo<Mapped, 'str' | 'num'>>;


const foos: Foos = [fooStr, fooNum]
                    ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^

const map: Mapped = {
    str: 'foo',
    num: 42
}

foos.forEach((foo) => {
    const val = map[foo.value]
    foo.fun(val)
}
```

I get the error:

> Type 'Foo<Mapped, "str">' is not assignable to type 'Foo<Mapped, "str" | "num">'.

I can replace my union type by any, but then I get here:

```
const val = map[foo.value]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Mapped'.

<kbd>[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true&ts=4.3.5&ssl=36&ssc=31&pln=35&pc=24#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4YgE2QbwChkTkBnMKALnMtAHMAaY0kAVwFsb2OAjaQgF9ChMAE9syAGIB7GQB4AKo2QBpZBAAekEDjLIA1hDEyYyRQD5kAXgIsSANzgAbNhBqrmpZDDYgaABROzjSKANqqALoAlDZWPPxQANxCIggyIBQ%20cgDKlDSyCuhYuCoA5BRQZVa2RN7BbjQVlGVepL7%20yEEusdZWwQB0zhAg9GAAFqmE6Zlg2TIAcpwFcvLF2DjlPNU2dvUujchl220kHYHBvf0uUwD09w%20PT88vr28PIoT34pKF%20rYAQSgUDgYnkhTWmA25UqZWQAB8jtsLBYUqIJCg-rsgSCwRD1qVkHAQGIUWiZlkYHIyCsZP9kGEqTI8lAVEylhxImkMlkOJgaAS8LV7LRqEcma0RTwaAAWABMUyZZAGVKgAFFEOMAgEmVc9qQKXNgrs%20RhGXIBg0IFzvEyVX5us5okJokA)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This problem has 2 parts to be solved.

1- You are defining the `Foos` type as an array of objects that have unions within, when in fact, what you want is an array with a **union of the different possible objects** that can be within.

```
type Foos = Array<Foo<Mapped, 'str'> | Foo<Mapped, 'num'>>;
```

2- Next problem, inside the `forEach` there is no way to TypeScript to know what it is dealing with without any hints, so the best way to do this, is with a **type guard**, to check if `foo` is a `mappedStr` or a `mappedNum`, that way we can assert the type of `foo` and use it's `fun` function.

```
function isMappedStr(foo: Foo<Mapped, 'str'> | Foo<Mapped, 'num'>): foo is Foo<Mapped, 'str'>  {
    return foo.value === "str";
}

foos.forEach((foo) => {
    const val = map[foo.value]
    if(isMappedStr(foo)){
        foo.fun(String(val))
    }else{
        foo.fun(Number(val));
    }
})
```

Here is a link to [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true&ts=4.3.5&ssl=46&ssc=3&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4YgE2QbwChkTkBnMKALnMtAHMAaY0kAVwFsb2OAjaQgF9ChMAE9syAGIB7GQB4AKo2QBpZBAAekEDjLIA1hDEyYyRQD5kAXgIsSANzgAbNhBqrmpZDDYgaABROzjSKANqqALoAlDZWPPxQANxCIggyIBQ%20cgDKlDSyCuhYuCoA5BRQZVa2RN7BbjQVlGVepL7%20yEEusdZWwQB0zhAg9GAAFqmE6Zlg2TIAcpwFcvLF2DjlPNU2dvUujchl220kHYHBvf0uUwD09w%20PT88vr28PIqISKIX6tgCCUCgcDE8kKa0wG3KlR2AB9pKt1qUjtsLBYUoR7uJJL9doDgaDwUjNsg4CAxGiMTMsjA5GQVjI-sgwrSZHkoCpWUsOJE0hkshxMDRibs6qRKk1Wa17MgeDQACwAJimHQQYGAGWQwDIxPZAVZDIhJRJzSqVnhRMhyOOnGq0RorK1%20ktxuhLSse1IUAgYDYUBA8wGDRQ1lDyAARJVwylhIRWWQBrSoABRRDjAL6uRXT0kalzYK7QUYFlyIMHCC87zAGABbW6yiZmTRaJi7xnUsdALshjdZzNmWCCDOMgQVtt1mJvwBbmJXvNlLeYSCaJAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although in my MWE, i have two types in the union, but in my case I have many types, and possibly even more...